# Share same generated id for Mongo Document and JPA Entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to have one object definition as Entity and Document and share/use the same generated id to store in DB? Mongo requires String as object id (can be generated without problem) but in JPA String cannot be generated. In case Long is used it can be easily generated by JPA but it cannot be generated by Mongo. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
@Entity
@Document
public class DocHeader {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use uuid  strategy :

```
  @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid" )
    private String id;
```

Also you can use guid to generate String id :

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "guid" )
    @GenericGenerator(name = "guid", strategy = "guid")
private String id;
```